# Which Android SDK version contains Chrome 5 Beta?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to know the Min Android SDK version which contains Chrome 5 beta. How can I know this information?

Comment: What's the connection between Android (a Linux based phone operating system) and Chrome (a web browser for multiple platforms, but excluding Android)?

Answer (score 2):

The Android platform does not use the Google Chrome browser (at least not yet - there have been rumors about a "Chrome Lite" for mobile platforms). In the meantime, the native Android browser does incorporate a number of things from Chrome, including the [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't have a chrome browser. Its browser is simply called "browser". 
Android and chrome are two different project (teams?) at google.. More info [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/179-chrome-mobile-android-browser/)

I suppose you will only have chrome like browser on Android and never chrome itself.